# Undocumented Synaptic options?

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, synaptic

Where can I find information about hidden Synaptic commands such as `synaptic --hide-main-window --non-interactive --parent-window-id --set-selections-file --progress-str --finish-str` and also internal options like `-o Synaptic::closeZvt=true` etc? I see these commands called in programs like AptURL or MintInstall but I cannot find documentation for them.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? LinuxMint is off-topic here.

Comment: I have Ubuntu MATE Focal and Mint 20. I have synaptic installed in both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: these arguments are not documented in [`man synaptic`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/synaptic.8.html) and in builtin help (`synaptic --help`) either.

So the only possible way to know what these options really do is to read the source code of Synaptic application - [check `gtk/gsynaptic.cc`](https://github.com/mvo5/synaptic/blob/b342ecde24aeaf5ab770714cf95a2d34cda9ffef/gtk/gsynaptic.cc) to get some details.

Comment: Thank you! The link you gave is very useful: it even contains additional commands I wasn't aware of. I guess you are right: the only way to understand how they work is to study the source. I'm reading it now.